# Using base X, how high can I count using Y characters?

Tags: math, permutation, factorial

I know that the total number of permutations for a given base is the factorial... so the total number of permutations of "abc" is `3!` or `3x2x1` or `6`.

Obviously I'm not sure of the terminology to properly phrase my question, but I would like to find the highest numbered permutation before the "length" of it's representation increases to X characters.

For example, Using a Base 62 'alphabet', I can represent integers up to 238327 before the representation uses 4 characters instead of 3. I'd like to know the math behind finding this out, given arbitrary values for Base and Length of representation.

Essentially, "using Base-X, how high can I count using Y characters?".

Comment: I should take a basic maths class. This makes me feel ridiculous. =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your numbers are positive and start at 0 then you can count from `0` to `X^Y - 1`.

As per your example above, `62^3 - 1 = 238328 - 1 = 238327`.

Comment: Ah, exactly! I knew it was `base*base*...` times the number of characters, but somehow my brain would not provide me the `^` to pull this off at runtime. Augh. Thanks!